# What does the proximitiy_* cookie for when using OKTA for authentication

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, okta, okta-api, okta-signin-widget

I am trying to understand what the proximity_* OKTA cookie means when we log into a platform using OKTA for authentication. We need this information to add it to our cookie policy disclosure.

Searching OKTA documentation shown nothing about this cookie